# @font-face not working on chrome or firefox

Tags: css, web, font-face

This has been happening on a couple of websites I've been developing as of late and I'm utterly confused why. None of the other answers on Stack Overflow seem to help me, nor any other resource I've found on google seem to have an answer for me. I'm thinking I'm doing something stupid, but what?

Here is the website I'm currently frustrated with: http://atonea.com/csj/

It won't work on Chrome or Firefox, but it will work on Safari. Which just doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: Dev tools says `http://atonea.com/csj/fontt/GILLUBCD.ttf 404 NOT Found` - also let `@font-face` go at the beginning of your CSS.

Comment: You can create multiple files for the fonts you used in your web-pages. This way you can got it worked on every major browser. for generator see http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're only including the [`.ttf`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TrueType) format which is for certain versions of WebKit, instead include multiple font formats for cross-browser support:

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'MyWebFont';
src: url('webfont.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
src: url('webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
     url('webfont.woff') format('woff'), /* Modern Browsers */
     url('webfont.ttf')  format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
     url('webfont.svg#svgFontName') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
}
```

You also need to add the `@font-face` rule before using it on any element ..

Comment: That worked, but I don't understand why. How does adding multiple formats suddenly allow chrome to accept it? Was it just chrome was looking for a format that wasn't there?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add your font-face before declaring it. So place your font face at the beginning of your css.

Comment: I had that originally, no difference. You can check it now.